# solr search with whitespaces and without whitespaces

Tags: solr

I want to search products in the document with whitespaces and without whitespaces like `"base ball"`, `"baseball"`

if someone searches for "baseball" the result should fetch the records of "baseball" & "base ball"

I am not able to that, also i do not want to use "synonyms" for that.

I have used filter class `"WordDelimiterFilterFactory"` to get that results i use keywords like sunglass for sun glass, keychain for key chain in synonyms files.

but there will be much more words like this so it's been difficult to find such words whose meaning is same even after split.

so I am looking for the solution where I don't have to use synonyms to get the desired result

I've tried by setting `catenateWords='1'` to get that result but it also did not match the result.

Comment: if someone searches for "baseball" the result should fetch the records of "baseball" & "base ball"...if there are indexes of the words baseball and base ball then yes ...it will fetch...But if the word is baseball...on what basis it will splitted into base and ball at the time of indexing?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without adding the synonyms. You should add the base ball as a synonyms to baseball.

The `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` is depricated.

Even if you use `WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory` its not possible.

`generateWordParts` : It spilts the words at camelcase like BaseBall...but its not the case for you.

`catenateWords` : It also wont work in your case as your word is not having any special char or hyphen separated to join. e.g wi-fi will get wifi.

So either you data should have the separate words to be indexed. It means if you dont want to use synonyms then you have to push baseball and base ball for indexing then only you will be able perform search on these words.